# State machine in C for SDL game

Tags: sdl, sdl2, c, statemachine

I want to create a state machine for menu in my SDL game. So this is my code without the SDL I just want to ask if this is a good way to create it.
here is a code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h> 
enum states
{
Menu,
Game,
Game_over,
Exit
};

int main()
{
 int game_is_running = 1;
 enum states state = Menu;
 while(game_is_running == 1)
{
  switch(state)
 {
  case Menu:
    state = Game;
    printf("menu screen with play and exit button.\n"); //need to add if 
                                                //exit or play is pressed 
                     // if exit then exit program if play than you know...
     break;
    case Game:
     state = Game_over;
    printf("after play button is pressed game screen will show up.\n"); //after this i will come back to menu.
    break;
  case Game_over:
    state = Exit;
    printf("screen after game.\n");
    break;
  case Exit:
    printf("turn game off.\n"); //this will be in the if function with a game.
    game_is_running = 0;
    break;
}
 Sleep(1000); // sleep for a second just for test
}
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Is this a good way to do it" is something that codereview.stackexchange.com is better suited to.

Comment: ou i didn't know about that page. Thank you